# python3-pyds9 package missing in Jessie

Tags: debian, python

In Sid there is a package `python3-pyds9` but it seems this disappeared in Jessie. How do I get ds9 package for Python in Jessie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package didn't disappear from Debian 8 (Jessie), it wasn't part of the release.

[`python-pyds9`](https://tracker.debian.org/python-pyds9) (which provides the `python3-pyds9` package) builds just fine on Debian 8, so the easiest way to do this is (currently):

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install devscripts debhelper dh-python python{,3}-setuptools python{,3}-six
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-pyds9/python-pyds9_1.8.1-1.dsc
cd python-pyds9-1.8.1
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This will:

- install the packages necessary to download, extract and build the `python-pyds9` source,
- download, verify and extract the source package,
- and build the binary packages.

You'll find the resulting `python-pyds9_1.8.1-1_all.deb` and `python3-pyds9_1.8.1-1_all.deb` packages in the parent directory.